# How to create iphone widget with react native

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, react-native, widget

[image]

(Image from apple support)

I have tried to build a widget. but even there is no documentation or whatever I can refer. please let me know generously.

how to build this widget with react native and expo.

I have been using "Expo" for developing.

Thankyou.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/matejkriz/react-native-today-widget/

Comment: I did already I think today widget and the widget in the image are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to edit native code to build a widget, it will be difficult with expo, here is [good example](https://github.com/surialabs/react-native-widget-example) how to do it.